# Error: Could not find or load main class when run the program

Tags: java

I have started to learn JAVA program recently and during that i am facing issue to run program. my program is like below

```
package mypack;
class Balance {

  //some here
}
class AccountBalance {

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        //some code here
    }
}
```

And my directory is like `E:\Local\Desktop\JAVA>`,it complied successfully and generated two class files `AccountBalance.class` and `Balance.class`. but it not run successfully. see below error

```
E:\Local\Desktop\JAVA>javac AccountBalance.java

E:\Local\Desktop\JAVA>java AccountBalance
Error: Could not find or load main class AccountBalance
```

Now interesting thing is if i got one directory up and run then it successfully run

```
E:\Local\Desktop>java JAVA.AccountBalance
--> Tom Jackson: $-12.33
```

So anyone have idea about where is the issue?

Edit:

Changing package name from JAVA to mypack not resolving issue

```
E:\Local\Desktop\mypack>javac AccountBalance.java

E:\Local\Desktop\mypack>java AccountBalance
Error: Could not find or load main class AccountBalance

E:\Local\Desktop\mypack>
```

linked answer doesn't help to answer this question anyway. As i am giving perfectly valid target in argument to run program.

Comment: The name of the class is `JAVA.AccountBalance`, you have to use that name or it doesn't work.

Comment: Do not name your package *JAVA*. BTW The package name should be lower case by naming conventions

Comment: (Also there already is a package named `java` in the standard API, so using that as a package name is a terrible idea.)

Comment: the linked answer to this question is not giving answer of my question. As i am giving perfect target to run program.

Comment: Don't know why this question closed without it being answered or very well explained. close rights misused on new contributors.

Comment: Downvote for stupid title. Be specific.

Comment: @user207421 and now?

Answer (score 1):

if you are creating class under any package you need to put that in specific directory
put your java file in a folder named `JAVA`
now run the below command from outside of that folder

```
javac JAVA.AccountBalance
```

and than run as  `java JAVA.AccountBalance` as you have created it with specific package

btw, as standards , you should have named package something other than JAVA and also standard is to name package in all small letters.

Comment: ```E:\Local\Desktop>javac JAVA.AccountBalance
error: Class names, 'JAVA.AccountBalance', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested
1 error```

Comment: have your complied it before running, also rename package to something else than JAVA.

Comment: ```javac JAVA.AccountBalance
``` isn't this command to compile?

Comment: changing package name not resolving it. still same error. ```E:\Local\Desktop\mypack>javac AccountBalance.java

E:\Local\Desktop\mypack>java AccountBalance
Error: Could not find or load main class AccountBalance

E:\Local\Desktop\mypack>```

Comment: what is your java file name?

Comment: java JAVA\AccountBalance.java is right way to compile.

Comment: my file name is ```AccountBalance.java```.